# R shiny error: Cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'

Tags: r

I would like to take in a vector of numbers as input and then simply plot the histogram. Here is my R code:

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(

  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),

  sidebarPanel(selectInput("Vector", "Select Numbers", c(1,2,3,4), selected = NULL, multiple = TRUE)),

  mainPanel( plotOutput("plotVector"))
))
```

Server.R:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

v<- function()
 {
  v <- rnorm(input$Vector)#take vector as input
}

  output$plotVector <- renderPlot({  hist(as.numeric(v))}) 

})
```

code to run the app:

```
library(shiny)
runApp("C:/Users/me/Desktop/R Projects/testShiny")
```

When I run this I am getting the error "Cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'"

Can you help? Thank you.

Comment: A "closure" is a function -- somewhere in there you've invoked a function (by name) rather than some variable.

Comment: So how do I return the data fromt he function and NOT the function itself? Any idea?Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

On the server side, you define v as a function:

```
v<- function()
 {
  v <- rnorm(input$Vector)#take vector as input
}
```

and then you try to use it as the argument to `as.numeric(...)`:

```
output$plotVector <- renderPlot({  hist(as.numeric(v))})
```

so R is trying to convert something of class: function to double.

**Edit**: to answer OP's followup question. With the following for ui.R and server.R:

On the server side, `shinyUI(...)` takes two objects which are passed automatically: `input` and `output`. The properties of `input` ("columns" in R terminology) are defined in ui.R by creating various GUI objects. So you create a `select` object with a call to `selectInput(...)`. The object's id is `"Vector"`. This is referenced on the server side as: `input$Vector`. Note that what you are calling `Vector` is actually a single number: whatever the user selects in the select box. Plotting the histogram of a single number is meaningless, so I changed the code to make input$Vector the mean of a normal distribution. You also had the problem that input$Vector was initialized to NULL in your code, which threw an error. So I changed that to initialize to 0.

The statement:

```
output$mainplot <- ...
```

on the server side populates an object `output$main_plot` in `ui.R`, which is defined by the statement:

```
... plotOutput("main_plot")...
```

Rolling it all up, the following:

**ui.R:**

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Hello Shiny!"),
  sidebarPanel(selectInput("Vector", "Select Mean of Distribution", c(0,1,2,3,4), selected = 0, multiple = TRUE)),
  mainPanel( plotOutput("main_plot"))
))
```

**server.R:**

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  v<- function() {
    return(rnorm(100,mean=as.numeric(input$Vector)))  
  }
  output$main_plot <- 
    renderPlot( 
      hist(v(), breaks=10, xlab="",
           main="Histogram of 100 Samples\n taken from: N[mean, sd=1]")) 
})
```

Generates this:

[image]

Comment: So how do I return the data fromt he function and NOT the function itself? Any idea?Thank you.

Comment: @user3022875  Jhoward beat me to identifying the error by seconds :-), but your question misses the point: you need to remove the `v<-` from the body of your function. Then `v(x)` will return the vector of data which `hist` expects.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like doing  this works!

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

v<- function()
 {
  v <- rnorm(input$Vector)#take vector as input
}

  output$plotVector <- renderPlot({  
data <- v()
hist(data)
    }) 

})
```