# R shiny: closure to double with TermDocumentMatrix?

Tags: r, shiny

I've tried using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430171/r-shiny-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double) as a guide for my problem to no avail and was hoping someone could easily see my mistake.

I'm getting the same error of "*Error in as.double(y) :   cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'*", but I'm trying to [plot a TermDocumentMatrix](http://tm.r-forge.r-project.org/faq.html#TermDocumentMatrixPlot) by using Shiny. My code is as follows:

ui.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)

shinyUI(navbarPage("Test", id="nav",
  tabPanel("Correlation Plot",
  progressInit(),

  # Sidebar with a slider and selection inputs
  sidebarPanel(width = 5,
               selectInput("selection", "Choose a reason:", 
                           choices = books),
               actionButton("update", "Change"),
               hr(),
               sliderInput("freq", 
                           "Minimum Frequency:", 
                           min = 1,  max = 50, value = 15),
               sliderInput("correl", 
                           "Correlation Threshold:", 
                           min = 0,  max = 1,  value = 0.8)
  ),

  # Show plot
  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("cplot")
  )
  )
))
```

global.R

```
library(tm)
library(wordcloud)
library(memoise)

# The list of valid books
books <<- list("1" = "1", "2"= "2")

# Using "memoise" to automatically cache the results
getTermDoc <- memoise(function(book) {
  if (!(book %in% books))
    stop("Unknown book")

  text = read.table(sprintf("./%s.txt", book),sep="\r",quote="")

  myCorpus = Corpus(VectorSource(text))
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeNumbers)
  myCorpus = tm_map(myCorpus, removeWords,stopwords("english"))
  myDTM = TermDocumentMatrix(myCorpus)

})
```

server.R

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyIncubator)
library(tm)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  # Define a reactive expression for the document term matrix
   doc <- reactive({
    # Change when the "update" button is pressed...
    input$update
    # ...but not for anything else
    isolate({
      withProgress(session, {
        setProgress(message = "Processing corpus...")
        getTermDoc(input$selection)
      })
    })
  })

  plot_rep <- repeatable(plot)
  #correlation plot
    output$cplot <- renderPlot({
        plot_rep(doc, 
            terms = findFreqTerms(doc, lowfreq = 500),
            #terms = findFreqTerms(doc, lowfreq = input$freq),          
            #weighting = TRUE,
            corThreshold = 0.975
            #corThreshold = input$correl
            #nodeAttrs=list(fillcolor=vc)
            )
  })

})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call

```
doc <- reactive({...})
```

the `reactive` call is essentially returning a function that you must call to get the value of `doc`. So instead of

```
plot_rep(doc, 
    terms = findFreqTerms(doc, lowfreq = 500)
```

use

```
plot_rep(doc(), 
    terms = findFreqTerms(doc()), lowfreq = 500)
```