# cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character' rgl package

Tags: r, rgl

I am using the rgl package to create an interactive .html file but I am getting an error in line 42. I am fairly new to this package and can't seem to define rgl_init function in line 44, so any help will be appreciated. I did find a solution ([R shiny error: Cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20430171/r-shiny-error-cannot-coerce-type-closure-to-vector-of-type-double)), but I don't know how to implement it to this code.

```
#3D convex hull of the individual tree LiDAR-derived
#Import the LAS file
LAS_File <- system.file("test.las")
#Reading
library(rLiDAR)
LAS <- readLAS("D:/Summer_2019/NRS_Project/01_data/01_las_2013/test.las")
#Setup the coordinates and data subsetting
xyz <- subset(LAS[,1:3],LAS[,3] >= 1.37)
#Find the clusters
clLAS<-kmeans(xyz, 32)
#Setup the id vector
ID<-as.factor(clLAS$cluster)
#Setting the alpha
Alpha<-0.6
#Setting the plotCAS parameter
plotit=TRUE
#Setting the convex hull color
col="forestgreen"
#Combine the xyz and id
xyzID<-cbind(xyz,ID)
#Computing the volume and surface area
library(rgl)
open3d()
voumelist<-chullLiDAR3D(xyzid = xyzID, plotit = plotit, col = col, alpha = Alpha)
summary(voumelist) 
#summary
#Write CSV file
write.table(voumelist, file = 'test_volume.csv', row.names=FALSE,col.names=FALSE)
write.csv(voumelist, "test_volume.csv")
#Adding plot parameters
#Adding the 3D point cloud
plot3d(xyzID[, 1:3], col = xyzID[,4], add=TRUE)
#Axis
axes3d(c("x+", "y-", "z-"))
#Grids
grid3d(side = c('x+', 'y-', 'z'), col='gray')
title3d(xlab="UTM Easting", ylab="UTM Northing", zlab = "Height", col="red")
#Scaling
aspect3d(1,1,0.7)
#Save HTML file
library(rmarkdown)
writeWebGL(dir = "D:/Summer_2019/NRS_Project/01_data/01_las_2013", filename = file.path(dir, "D:/Summer_2019/NRS_Project/01_data/01_las_2013/Test_index.html"))
#Write a copy to display in Chrome
rgl_init()
rgl.spheres(x, y, z, r = 0.2, 
            color = get_colors(iris$Species)) 
rgl_add_axes(x, y, z, show.bbox = FALSE)
# This writes a copy into temporary directory 'webGL',
# and then displays it
browseURL(
  paste("D:/Summer_2019/NRS_Project/01_data/01_las_2013/Test_index.html", writeWebGL(dir=file.path(tempdir(), "D:/Summer_2019/NRS_Project/01_data/01_las_2013"), 
                              width=500), sep="")
)
```

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible.  We don't have your data, or the `rgl_init` function, or `rgl_add_axes`.  Don't use `writeWebGL`, use `rglwidget`.  `writeWebGL` has been deprecated for several years now.

Comment: Alright, I give it a try, thank you.